# XMPP FileTransfer - Why does the bytestreams protocol fail?

Tags: android, cocoa-touch, proxy, xmpp, openfire

I'm doing file transfer via XMPP on both Android and iOS to a Spark client (Spark 2.6.3). I have successfully accomplished this on android (due to the nice libraries) but have yet to succeed on iOS. However, on *both* devices I have noticed that the transfer fails via bytestreams ...

```
<error code="404" type="CANCEL"><item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" xml:lang="en">Could not establish socket with any provided host</text></error>
```

On Android the transfer completes by resorting to ibb ...

```
<iq id="DK1IO-19" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="set"><open xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" block-size="4096" sid="jsi_4740809287923906297" stanza="iq"/></iq>
```

Also, on Android, when I send a file from Spark to my Android app, it seems to work fine via bytesreams.

On iOS therefore I would have to code the ibb connection myself, but why would bytestreams be failing in the first place?

**Full Logs (android app) :**

```
05-15 13:42:04.023: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-9" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123" from="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="result"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="stream-method"><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value></field></x></feature></si></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.040: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM SENT (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-10" to="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="get"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.060: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-10" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123" type="result" from="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="client" name="Smack" type="pc"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/commands"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"/></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.080: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM SENT (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-11" to="beta.example.co.uk" type="get"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.090: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq type="result" id="DK1IO-11" from="beta.example.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"><item jid="pubsub.beta.example.co.uk" name="Publish-Subscribe service"/><item jid="broadcast.beta.example.co.uk" name="Broadcast service"/><item jid="search.beta.example.co.uk" name="User Search"/><item jid="conference.beta.example.co.uk" name="Public Chatrooms"/><item jid="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" name="Socks 5 Bytestreams Proxy"/></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.100: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM SENT (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-12" to="pubsub.beta.example.co.uk" type="get"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.110: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-10" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123" type="result" from="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="client" name="Smack" type="pc"/><feature var="http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html#ns"/><feature var="urn:xmpp:tmp:jingle"/></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.130: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq type="result" id="DK1IO-12" from="pubsub.beta.example.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="pubsub" name="Publish-Subscribe service" type="service"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#collections"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#config-node"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-and-configure"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-nodes"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#delete-nodes"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#get-pending"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#instant-nodes"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#item-ids"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#meta-data"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#modify-affiliations"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#manage-subscriptions"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#multi-subscribe"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#outcast-affiliation"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#persistent-items"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#presence-notifications"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publish"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publisher-affiliation"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#purge-nodes"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retract-items"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-affiliations"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-default"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-items"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-subscriptions"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscribe"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscription-options"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#default_access_model_open"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.160: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM SENT (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-13" to="broadcast.beta.example.co.uk" type="get"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.170: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq type="result" id="DK1IO-13" from="broadcast.beta.example.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="component" type="generic" name="Broadcast service"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.190: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM SENT (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-14" to="search.beta.example.co.uk" type="get"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.200: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq type="result" id="DK1IO-14" from="search.beta.example.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="directory" type="user" name="User Search"/><feature var="jabber:iq:search"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"/></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.210: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM SENT (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-15" to="conference.beta.example.co.uk" type="get"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.230: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq type="result" id="DK1IO-15" from="conference.beta.example.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="conference" name="Public Chatrooms" type="text"/><identity category="directory" name="Public Chatroom Search" type="chatroom"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/><feature var="jabber:iq:search"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"/></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.240: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM SENT (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-16" to="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" type="get"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.250: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq type="result" id="DK1IO-16" from="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.t
05-15 13:42:04.250: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM RCV  (1093423288): xttools.co.uk/123"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="proxy" name="SOCKS5 Bytestreams Service" type="bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.330: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM SENT (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-17" to="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" type="get"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.341: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq type="result" id="DK1IO-17" from="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"><streamhost jid="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" host="127.0.1.1" port="7777"/></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.350: I/System.out(523): 01:42:04 PM SENT (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-18" to="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="set"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="jsi_4740809287923906297" mode = "tcp"><streamhost jid="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123" host="127.0.0.1" port="7777"/><streamhost jid="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" host="127.0.1.1" port="7777"/></query></iq>
05-15 13:42:04.400: D/dalvikvm(523): GC_CONCURRENT freed 361K, 5% free 9330K/9799K, paused 5ms+4ms
05-15 13:42:09.412: I/System.out(523): 01:42:09 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-18" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123" from="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="error"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="jsi_4740809287923906297" mode="tcp"><streamhost jid="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123" host="127.0.0.1" port="7777"/><streamhost jid="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" host="127.0.1.1" port="7777"/></query><error code="404" type="CANCEL"><item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" xml:lang="en">Could not establish socket with any provided host</text></error></iq>
05-15 13:42:09.430: I/System.out(523): 01:42:09 PM SENT (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-19" to="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="set"><open xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" block-size="4096" sid="jsi_4740809287923906297" stanza="iq"/></iq>
05-15 13:42:09.451: I/System.out(523): 01:42:09 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-19" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123" from="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="result"/>
05-15 13:42:09.470: I/System.out(523): 01:42:09 PM SENT (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-20" to="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="set"><data xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" seq="0" sid="jsi_4740809287923906297">SGVsbG8sIEFuZHkh</data></iq>
05-15 13:42:09.480: I/System.out(523): 01:42:09 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-20" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123" from="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="result"/>
05-15 13:42:09.490: I/System.out(523): 01:42:09 PM SENT (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-21" to="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="set"><close xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb" sid="jsi_4740809287923906297"/></iq>
05-15 13:42:09.500: I/System.out(523): 01:42:09 PM RCV  (1093423288): <iq id="DK1IO-21" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123" from="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="result"/>
```

**Full Logs (iOS app) :**

```
2012-05-16 10:41:16.988 JabberClient[392:207] RECIEVED IN APP DELEGATE - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="5CCE541D-A2D2-4115-8D0F-A683EE9B18AB" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/844b40b3" from="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="result"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="stream-method"><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></field></x></feature></si></iq>
2012-05-16 10:41:16.989 JabberClient[392:207] Attempting XEP65 connection to friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3
2012-05-16 10:41:16.990 JabberClient[392:207] TURNSocket DELEGATE STARTING
2012-05-16 10:41:16.991 JabberClient[392:5307] SENT - <iq type="get" to="beta.example.co.uk" id="24C8A655-1B23-4E49-B0D2-557B863C6EB4"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/></iq>
2012-05-16 10:41:16.999 JabberClient[392:5307] RECIEVED IN TURN SOCKET - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="24C8A655-1B23-4E49-B0D2-557B863C6EB4" from="beta.example.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/844b40b3"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"><item jid="pubsub.beta.example.co.uk" name="Publish-Subscribe service"/><item jid="broadcast.beta.example.co.uk" name="Broadcast service"/><item jid="search.beta.example.co.uk" name="User Search"/><item jid="conference.beta.example.co.uk" name="Public Chatrooms"/><item jid="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" name="Socks 5 Bytestreams Proxy"/></query></iq>
2012-05-16 10:41:17.000 JabberClient[392:5307] SENT - <iq type="get" to="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" id="A8D03520-2200-4260-A150-910BC70F794A"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></iq>
2012-05-16 10:41:17.004 JabberClient[392:5007] RECIEVED IN TURN SOCKET - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="A8D03520-2200-4260-A150-910BC70F794A" from="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/844b40b3"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="proxy" name="SOCKS5 Bytestreams Service" type="bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></query></iq>
2012-05-16 10:41:17.005 JabberClient[392:5007] SENT - <iq type="get" to="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" id="50A73193-944D-402D-B2E4-EEACC537B23B"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/></iq>
2012-05-16 10:41:17.008 JabberClient[392:5007] RECIEVED IN TURNSOCKET - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="50A73193-944D-402D-B2E4-EEACC537B23B" from="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/844b40b3"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"><streamhost jid="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" host="127.0.1.1" port="7777"/></query></iq>
2012-05-16 10:41:17.009 JabberClient[392:5007] SENT - <iq type="set" from="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/844b40b3" to="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" id="5CCE541D-A2D2-4115-8D0F-A683EE9B18AB"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="5CCE541D-A2D2-4115-8D0F-A683EE9B18AB" mode="tcp"><streamhost xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" jid="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" host="127.0.1.1" port="7777"/></query></iq>
2012-05-16 10:41:27.027 JabberClient[392:540b] RECIEVED IN TURN SOCKET - <iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="5CCE541D-A2D2-4115-8D0F-A683EE9B18AB" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/844b40b3" from="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="error"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="5CCE541D-A2D2-4115-8D0F-A683EE9B18AB" mode="tcp"><streamhost jid="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" host="127.0.1.1" port="7777"/></query><error code="404" type="CANCEL"><item-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" lang="en">Could not establish socket with any provided host</text></error></iq>
2012-05-16 10:41:27.028 JabberClient[392:540b] TURN Connection failed!
```

**OpenFire XMPP settings -**

```
xmpp.auth.anonymous - true
xmpp.client.compression.policy - disabled
xmpp.client.idle -1
xmpp.client.idle.ping - false
xmpp.domain - beta.example.co.uk
xmpp.enabled - true
xmpp.externalip - proxy.beta.example.co.uk
xmpp.offline.quota - 102400
xmpp.offline.type - bounce
xmpp.proxy.enabled - true
xmpp.proxy.port - 7777
xmpp.proxy.transfer.required - true
xmpp.server.compression.policy - disabled
xmpp.server.socket.active - true
xmpp.session.conflict-limit - 0
xmpp.session.conflict.limit - 0
xmpp.socket.ssl.active - true
```

**Update 19th May:** Below are some logs from where Spark successfully sends *to* android (rather than vice-versa). The streamhost used isn't the proxy! However, I've not yet manage to replicate this on iOS, and really should I? Shouldn't proxy be working?

```
RCV  (1079219752): <iq id="ktI51-43" to="myUsername@beta.example.co.uk/123" type="set" from="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams" sid="jsi_1985730781887292843" mode="tcp"><streamhost jid="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" host="10.95.xxx.xx" port="7777"/><streamhost jid="proxy.beta.example.co.uk" host="127.0.1.1" port="7777"/></query></iq>
SENT (1079219752): <iq id="ktI51-43" to="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" type="result"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"><streamhost-used jid="friendsUsername@beta.example.co.uk/Spark 2.6.3" /></query></iq>
```

Note that if I try and send from Spark to my iOS app, when the non-proxy streamhost is used, the connection is refused! (as in point 6 of this [SOCKS Protocol Version 5](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt) document). Rep is 5 in the following code, (but it should be 0).

```
UInt8 ver = [NSNumber extractUInt8FromData:data atOffset:0];
UInt8 rep = [NSNumber extractUInt8FromData:data atOffset:1];
```

**Hosts File :** (note: I've replaced some numbers with x's for this Stack Overflow question)

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
10.95.xxx.xxx   intranet.example.co.uk
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
10.95.xxx.xxx   beta.example.co.uk
```

Comment: There were some bugs in [file transfer in Spark 2.6.3](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/index.jsp) that may be causing this. I would suggest you try the Beta version of 2.7.x and see if it persists.

Comment: Looks like no streamhost could be reached. But only one XMPP stanza is far to less to tell the reason for the failing transfer.

Comment: Robin : Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I am using a Mac, and Spark 2.7.0 beta doesn't seem to be available for Mac yet. Having said that,  the website implies that the big bug fix with file transfer is with IBB. I see no mention of bytestreams.

Comment: Flow : Thanks for your response, that's a fair point. I have added the full logs to my question from my android project.

Comment: Also, if it does indeed seem like no streamhost could be reached, I don't understand why, and I don't know what step to take next. Could it be relevant that the OpenFire server is on my LAN?

Comment: I've added the iOS logs to my question. Also, I've added my OpenFire XMPP Settings in case they are relevant. Is there any other info I should provide?

Comment: More updates to my question added. Can anybody help? I think the key issue is the connection is refused,

Comment: See if this helps - http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/44911

Comment: Hi userSeven7s! Thanks for your response! I'm a little confused as to whether your link relates to my problem, mainly because the bug you refer to is for IBB transfers. Shouldn't bytestream transfers still work, or am I misunderstanding something??? Also, if it is still relevant, I am using Spark 2.6.3 and I'm unsure what version of Smack it uses. My android app uses asmack-jse-buddycloud-2010.12.11.jar and again I'm not sure what version of Smack that uses. And iOS is nothing to do with Smack unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: Any comments or answers anyone? The Bounty is nearly finished?

Comment: The streamhost offered has the local ip address 127.0.0.1 as host which of course cannot work.
<streamhost jid="proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk" host="127.0.1.1" port="7777"/>
check if you can configure the host in your Openfire config.

Comment: Thankyou for your response Alex. My knowledge of this type of thing (servers, ip addresses, hosts etc) is where I have a lack of knowledge. Can you explain to me what I should be changing the ip address to?

Comment: to the public ip address of your streamhost proxy proxy.beta.myCompany.co.uk

Comment: Hi Alex. I'm back on this project after a small break. I have now posted my hosts file onto my question. I presume the 10.95.xxx.xxx ip address is the one you believe I should be setting on Openfire? I currently have been unable to spot how or where I can set this?

Comment: Aha! In Openfire I can set xmpp.proxy.externalip to either beta.myCompany.co.uk or the ip, and the 404 error no longer appears. However, file transfer doesn't automatically commence still.

Comment: I now receive the following error in my OpenFire logs : org.jivesoftware.openfire.filetransfer.proxy.ProxyConnectionManager - Error processing file transfer proxy connection 
java.io.IOException: Only SOCKS5 supported. (Possibly I need to set up a new stackoverflow question for this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the wrong setting in my OpenFire properties. `xmpp.externalip` is wrong. I needed to use `xmpp.proxy.enabledip` and set this to the public IP.

Comment: HI Where can i find  this Settings in open fire server@Andy A

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your server is reporting a steamhost (proxy) of `127.0.0.1`, or localhost, which is not correct.

I recently saw this on an openfire server that someone had configured `/etc/hosts` to point the server name to `127.0.0.1`, so that's what it reported to clients when it looked up its own name.

The easiest way to check this will be 'ping `<servername>`' and 'ping `<server FQDN>`', and see what IP addresses it comes up with.

For instance, if your server name was `beta.example.co.uk`, you'd try (While logged into the server):

ping beta
ping `beta.example.co.uk`

if either returns with an IP of `127.0.0.1`, check `/etc/hosts` (or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` if on windows) and make sure beta and `beta.example.co.uk` are not there (or have the appropriate data if they are there).

Comment: Hi Zack. Thanks so much for your comment. I've added my hosts file onto the question here. 127.0.0.1 is against localhost. Beta has a different ip address (which I think I needed to add for regular XMPP text messages to work). If I do 'ping beta.myCompany.co.uk' I get regular responses such as ... '64 bytes from 10.95.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=3.799 ms'. Does it appear there is still something incorrectly setup?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, file transfer will have this error. Don't use compiled library use the source code of smack for Android called amack/smack it will help you to trace the error. I did use the source code.

https://github.com/rtreffer/smack/blob/master/source/org/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPConnection.java